# How do I create apk file for a Xamarin.Android application

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk

I am new to android development and need to create an apk file for an android application I made in Xamarin Studios so my peer can test it on his device. How can I create the apk file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select **Build** menu next click **Archive for Publishing**
2. Right-Click on build which do you want get apk file next select **Sign and Distribute**
3. Select **Ad Hock** and click next button
4. Select testing certificate and click next button
5. **Publish** and choose where do you want save apk file.

Comment: Not able to find Archive for Publishing option.

Answer (score 6):

#### For even simpler/faster testing, you can:

- connect an Android phone to the USB and use it for debugging/testing.
  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development.
- build your app (as debug, for example)
- Every time you test on your phone by clicking on the "play button" [button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spQMa.png), it automatically creates an APK under bin\Debug\ or bin\Release.
- The file you are looking for is the "Signed apk", e.g. **com.companyname.MyApp-Signed.apk**
- Copy this file to the device using any method (I usually use USB or GDrive). On the device, download it and click on it to install.

## Important:

"Use Shared Runtime" inside the project properties/Android Options must be **Disabled**, otherwise Mono Runtime won't be included and your app will crash on phones where Mono isn't installed.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U46iC.png)

Comment: This is easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Visual Studio 2019 and the latest xamarin, I will literally walk you through all the steps:

0. Change your project from "Debug" mode to "Release" mode like below:

[image]

1. Build your android project first.
2. Right-click on your android project -> click "Archive..."
3. It'll show something like this: Let it complete its processing
   [image]
4. When it's done, click the "Distribute" button, it'll open a menu like this:

[image]

5. Click on the "Ad Hoc" button and click the "+" button like below:

[image]

6. fill the form and click the "Create" button

[image]

7. Select your saved settings and click the "Save As" button

[image]

8. Chose your location to save and save the APK file and get it from where you saved it :)

Answer (score 1):

For simple testing:

1. **Build** the project in **Release** mode
2. Go to your project's **/bin/Release** folder
3. Inside the folder, you will find the required **signed apk** file.
4. The **apk** file should now be installable simply by running it from an Android device.